# Reference of a pointer returning weird value

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Can anyone explain to me why this code works (why does it return a value)?

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr = new int(113);
    int &rPtr = *ptr;

    delete ptr;

    cout << rPtr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, this is the return value that I get:

```
-572662307
```

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Comment: What exactly made you ask this question? When people ask such questions, it means that they saw something different from what they expected to see. What did you expect to see in this case?

Comment: I didn't saw anything. I just got this idea on what would happen if I tried something like this so I tried it and got weird result so I decided to ask :D

Comment: @deadmau5 : [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) -- read up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing results in undefined behavior, so the fact that you're getting this number is perfectly reasonable behavior.

When you perform this sequence:

```
int *ptr = new int(113);
int &rPtr = *ptr;
```

The reference `rPtr` now refers to the integer you created with the line `new int(113)`.  On the next line, you execute

```
delete ptr;
```

This deletes that `int`, meaning that the object no longer exists.  Any pointers or references to it now reference a deallocated object, which causes undefined behavior.  Consequently, when you print `rPtr` with

```
cout << rPtr << endl;
```

Anything can happen.  Here, you're just getting garbage data, but the program easily could have crashed or reported a debug error message.

Interestingly: The value you printed (-572662307), treated as a 32-bit unsigned value, is 0xDDDDDDDD.  I bet this is the memory allocator putting a value into the deallocated memory to help you debug memory errors like this one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot on your response :)

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking **undefined behavior**. The reference is no longer valid after deleting the pointer:

```
int *ptr = new int(113);
int &rPtr = *ptr;
//rPtr references the memory ptr points to
delete ptr;
//the memory is released
//the reference is no longer valid
cout << rPtr << endl;
//you try to access an invalid reference
//anything can happen at this point
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference for object is alive in all block scope (in this case function scope), so when you delete pointer, some garbage was at this address and output shows it.